# Validation of phone numbers containing '+' and '-' characters

Tags: codeigniter

In CodeIgniter, how do i validate phone numbers containing '+' and '-' symbols?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot enter a number with "-" since you defined integer as the validation rule. Therefore, the validation will fail. You need to work with RegEx so that you can create more complex validation. See the topic on validations in the [CI manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) for more info.

Your validation rule:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('foo', 'Number', 'callback_number_validation');
Note how the keyword callback_ is used to identify CI your function for validation.
```

Your callback function:

```
//$str will be the value you want to verify
function number_validation($str) {
    return preg_match("your_regex", $str) ? true: false;
}
```

Comment: No need for ternary. Just `return preg_match("your_regex", $str);`